# Help to understand this exchange from comment of Yahoo article

Tags: reading-comprehension

> A: I don't agree with Omarosa on much, but **'difficult to watch' is as spot on as it gets**
>
> B: " . . . spot on . . . ", one of the most annoying phrases in the
>   English language.

I saw this exchange in a comment from [this Yahoo article](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/omarosa-believes-trump-apos-covets-161333153.html). I particularly don't quite understand the part in bold. I think "spot on" means "*exactly correct or accurate*". And also, why **B** said "*" . . . spot on . . . ", one of the most annoying phrases in the English language.*"?

Can someone help to spell it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two statements refer to unrelated things.  You are correct about "spot on" meaning exactly correct or accurate.

The exact context of the comment is hard to determine, but not really important.  They could be saying Omarosa and her behavior are difficult to watch, or what's happening to Omarosa is difficult to watch.

Person A is talking about how they think "difficult to watch" describes their own opinion.  "As spot on as it gets" means that "difficult to watch" is a perfect description of their own feelings.

Person B is commenting on person A's word choice, saying that the use of the phrase "spot on" is annoying.

Comment: In what way  does B feel 'spot on' annoying?

Comment: You would have to ask B.  :-)  Various people find various phrases annoying for various reasons.